# Java String replaceAll() method using {} curly brackets

Tags: java, string, replaceall

So for my app in Android Studio I want to replace the following:

```
String card = cards.get(count).getCard();
if (card.contains("{Player1}")) {
            String replacedCard = card.replaceAll("{Player1}", "Poep");
}
```

*An example of String card can be: {Player1} switch drinks with the person next to you.*

Somehow I can't use {} for the replacing. With the { it says: "Dangling metacharacter". Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/s2bbl8

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Consider using `String.replace` instead of `String.replaceAll`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the first Argument of `replaceAll` is a String that is parsed to a [regular Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (regEx). The braces `{ }` are special reserved meta characters to express something within the regular expression. To match them as normal characters, you need to escape them with a leading backslash `\` and because the backslash is also a special character you need to escape itself with an additional backslash:

```
String replacedCard = card.replaceAll("\\{Player1\\}", "Poep");
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `{ }` are reserved regex characters. Since the `replaceAll()` function takes in a regex parameter, you have to explicitly state that **`{`** and **`}`** are part of your actual string. You can do this by prefixing them with the escape character: `\`. But because the escape character is also a reserved character, you need to escape it too.

Here's the correct way to write your code:

```
String card = cards.get(count).getCard();
if (card.contains("{Player1}")) {
    String replacedCard = card.replaceAll("\\{Player1\\}", "Poep");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the initial { with \. I.e;

```java
        String card = "{Player1}";

        if (card.contains("{Player1}")) {
            String replacedCard = card.replaceAll("\\{Player1}", "Poep");

            System.out.println("replace: " + replacedCard);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the input value of the replaceAll method expects a regex, you need to escape the curly brackets with a backslash. The curly brackets are special characters in the context of regular expressions.

In Java a backslash in a regex is accomplished by a double backslash `\\` (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html for reference).

So you would need to adjust the line like so:

```
String replacedCard = card.replaceAll("\\{Player1\\}", "Poep");
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `String.replaceAll` expects a regular expression. The other answers already give a solution for this. However, if you don't need regular expressions, then you can also use [`String.replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
String replacedCard = card.replace("{Player1}", "Poep");
```

Answer (score 0):

{} are special characters for Regular Expressions. replaceAll method takes as first parameter a Regular Expressions, so if you want also to replace the curly brackets you have to skip them with \\ , as follow:

```
    String card = cards.get(count).getCard();
    if (card.contains("{Player1}")) {
        String replacedCard = card.replaceAll("\\{Player1}", "Poep");
    }
```